# Spring MVC 3 Issue with the resources tag

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to setup my first spring application and wanted to setup the mapping for the static content. However I get the following exception when loading my pages:

```
    org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Cannot locate BeanDefinitionParser for element [resources]
    Offending resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/springMVC-servlet.xml]
        org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.fatal(FailFastProblemReporter.java:59)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.fatal(ReaderContext.java:68)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.fatal(ReaderContext.java:55)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.findParserForElement(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:84)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.parse(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:73)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1335)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1325)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:135)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:93)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:493)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:390)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:178)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:149)
        org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:124)
        org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:93)
        org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130)
        org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:467)
        org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:397)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:442)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:458)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:339)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:306)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:127)
        javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
        org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
        org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
        org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
        org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
        org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
        org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
        org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

My servlet file is as follows:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
         xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd">

            <context:component-scan
                base-package="web.controller" />

         <!-- Enabling Spring MVC configuration through annotations -->
         <mvc:annotation-driven />
        <!--  Mapping Static Resources -->
        <mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="/resources/" />
        <mvc:resources mapping="/js/**" location="/js/" />
        <mvc:resources mapping="/img/**" location="/img/" />
```

Am I missing something in the declaration?

Comment: Which version of Spring are you using? And which jars?

Comment: Spring libraries am using are .. org.springframework.asm.jar
spring-beans-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-core-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-expression-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-web-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-webmvc-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar

Comment: You are referencing Spring 3.1 schemas in your XML file: `http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd`... maybe there is a clash with 3.0.3 classes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One problem with your files  is that you use Spring 3.0 jars but use 3.1 xml schema for `mvc` and `context`.

So:

- upgrade your jars to spring 3.1, or
- use the 3.0 xml schemas,

but do not try to use 3.1 xml schema with 3.0 jars, that will not work.

*BTW you should decide if you refer an schema with an explicit version, like you did for `mvc` and `contect` or use the latest from the jars, like you did for `beans`*

Example for using (explicit) 3.0 schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
     xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
     xsi:schemaLocation="
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">
```